# Алгоритм сжатия картинок

Tags: java, алгоритм

Необходимо сжать картинку к размеру `204 800 КБ`. Реализую сжатие при помощи `thumbnailator`. Думаю про вариант с `.scale(0.5)`. Если масштабиравать в 2 раза, то и размер в 2 раза уменьшится. Я так думал. Оказалось не так. Пытался вычислить коэффициент сжатия, безуспешно, значение постоянно меняется. Кто сможет подсказать варианты?

Если через цикл `for` пострадает производительность....

```
// create static size
        byte[] convertedImage;

        try (
                ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            ) {
            System.out.println("img.length "+img.length);
            Thumbnails.of(input).scale(1.0).outputFormat("gif").toOutputStream(output);
            convertedImage = output.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("convertedImage "+convertedImage.length);
        }
```

Comment: Два в квадрате - четые. Если без сжатия, то при масштабировании в 2 раза - размер меняется в 4 раза. Потому что к-во пикселей равно ширина*высота, и 0.5ширина*0.5высота=0.25 Учитывая сжатие - могут быть варианты (плюс поправка на заголовки) - По идее ответ - корень квадратный из коефициента отношения реального размера к нужному.

Comment: `204 800 КБ`? Это что за картинка такая, что ее надо уменьшать до 200 мегабайт?

Comment: @Yaant компромат на руководство))) Так много что сжимать нужно

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за наводку. Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import net.coobird.thumbnailator.Thumbnails;

/**
 *
 * @author Алексей
 */
public class Thumb2 {

    private static final double MAX_IMG_SIZE = 204800.00;

    public static byte[] scale(byte[] img) throws IOException {

        byte[] endImage;

        // create static size
        byte[] convertedImage;

        try (
                ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            ) {
            System.out.println("start.image.length "+img.length);
            Thumbnails.of(input).scale(1.0).outputFormat("gif").toOutputStream(output);
            convertedImage = output.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("after.edit.format.length "+convertedImage.length);
        }

        if (convertedImage.length <= MAX_IMG_SIZE) {
            endImage = convertedImage;
        } else {
            try (
                    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(convertedImage);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                ) {

                /*

                изначальный размер картинки: 814 099 Б
                необходимый размер картинки: 204 800 Б

                путем вычислений мы выяснили, что
                нужно срезать 609 299 Б:

                204 800 + x = 814 099
                x = 814 099 - 204 800
                x = 609 299

                дальше мы вычислили на сколько процентов 
                необходимо уманьшить размер картинки, а 
                именно на 74.84335443232334% :

                609 299 : 814 099 = 0.7484335443232334

                @author nick_n_a
                «Два в квадрате - четые. Если без сжатия, то при масштабировании 
                в 2 раза - размер меняется в 4 раза. Потому что к-во пикселей 
                равно ширина*высота, и 0.5ширина*0.5высота=0.25 Учитывая сжатие - 
                могут быть варианты (плюс поправка на заголовки) - По идее ответ - 
                корень квадратный из коефициента отношения реального размера 
                к нужному.»

                теперь необходимо получить scale-коэфициент для вставки
                1.00 - (0.7484335443232334 : 2) = 0.6257832278383833

                консоль:
                start.image.length 1 451 668
                after.edit.format.length 814 099
                convertedImage 362 935

                результат окозался выше на 158 135 Б
                возможно заголовок

                UPDATE:
                еслить удалить .outputFormat("gif"), то
                картинка сжимается до нужных размеров

                start.image.length 1451668
                after.edit.format.length 364646
                endImage 205762

                мо моему скромному мнению разница 
                в 962 Б не существенна

                */

                double startSize = (double) convertedImage.length;
                double destroySize = startSize - MAX_IMG_SIZE;
                double destroyProc = destroySize / startSize;
                double finalCoef = 1.00 - (destroyProc/2);

                Thumbnails.of(input).scale(finalCoef).outputFormat("gif").toOutputStream(output);
                endImage = output.toByteArray();

            }
        }
        System.out.println("endImage "+endImage.length);
        return endImage;
    }

}
```